# Apache Camel and CXF: Mutlitple cxf:rsServer tags .. is this possible?

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-404, apache-camel, cxfrs

I have been making restful webservices with cxf and camel, i came accross a strange issue i dont know if this is a normal camel behaviour or what.

I have multiple classes exposed as restful services and mapped to different paths. First i had only cxf in my configuration and i could expose all classes as services simultaneously. Now that i am also using camel i have tags like this :

```
    <camelcxf:rsServer id="rsServer1" address="/"
            serviceClass="com.something.PoiSearchImpl">
        </camelcxf:rsServer>
 <camelcxf:rsServer id="rsServer2" address="/"
            serviceClass="com.something.FooBarImpl">
        </camelcxf:rsServer>
```

After this i have  two routes which start from my cxf endpoints (described above ) and do some processing. Problem is only one of the service is working and other just doesnt gets invoked . it gives me 404 not found error. is this normal or i am missing something in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Sikorski,
Camel supports multiple cxf:rsServer. The problem with your approach is that both are mapped to an address '/'. This means that one of the servers is invoked.
```

Solution: You need to have unique address for each rsServer like below,

```
<camelcxf:rsServer id="rsServer1" address="/Bar" serviceClass="com.something.PoiSearchImpl">
</camelcxf:rsServer>
<camelcxf:rsServer id="rsServer2" address="/Foo" serviceClass="com.something.FooBarImpl">
</camelcxf:rsServer>
```

Comment: well its kinda late to tell me that, and i eventually figured it out. Now i am doing it in a different way and its already on "production". Regarding your line "problem with your approach" i would rather say problem was my approach altogether :D